# ImageView Change after SwipeTabs Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

After I take my Photo and Signature, it displays on the `ImageView`. However, after I swap the tabs the `ImageView` returns to its default Image. See my screenshot.

[image: sample image- screenshot]

There's no problem when it comes to `editText` the inputted value is still there. However, the `ImageView` is my problem. What's causing this problem? And how can I fix this?

Code:

```
public class RegisterUser extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register_user,container,false);
        // Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        // Create Navigation drawer and inlfate layout

        return v;
    }

    // Add Fragments to Tabs
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ListContentFragment(), "Info 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new TileContentFragment(), "info 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new CaptureSignatureActivity(), "info 3");
        adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "info 4");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you swipe through tabs (Fragments, actually) in a TabLayout, the default behaviour is that the system kills the previous `Fragment` to free memory and the subsequent Fragment to the current one will be loaded in the memory.

Now, with your code something similar is happening. When you load a photo and a signature in the 3rd tab (CaptureSignatureFragment) and then swipe through the tabs, the `CaptureSignatureFragment` is killed and thus both the ImageViews have the default images set to them.

If you wish to keep the data in the 3rd tab intact even after changing tabs, you should better set your ViewPager's `offscreen limit` to 4 (no. of tabs you have) by:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4)
```

Now, changing the tabs won't kill any of the `fragments`. However, doing this can create performance issues.

Comment: This fix my problem :) Thank you sir and btw thanks for info. Well Played!